# IIS 7 500 Error Handling situation

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

I am on IIS 7 with a Classic ASP application using `Server.GetLastError()` and i added this script that writes the error details to a database as a custom '500.100' error in IIS to execute this URL.  So far it's been working on most situations when there is an error in the application.  However, I am noticing in the IIS log that many people are getting `ASP_0147 | Internal Server Error` with a 500 error and no further explanation.

I am trying to catch this error showing up in the IIS Log using the method explained above, however, these errors are not being caught (written to database) using the application i made, whereas other types of errors are being caught, but the only errors that are being caught using the script/database i made, already show up with the entire error details in the IIS log.

So the question is, how can i catch the errors still happening in the IIS Log in the database using custom errors? because the method i'm using obviously isn't catching all the errors that show in the IIS Log, only the ones with an explanation being displayed in the log.  Or, if I change the Error 'Feature Settings' to 'Detailed Errors' (because now its set on, Detailed only for Local Requests) will it show up in the IIS log, etc?  Why am i only seeing 500 error in the IIS Log on certain things, but not on others? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an application stall.

If the server gets a lot of requests on the same time, causing the server to "get busy", it stalls some of the requests and possibly denying them. This could give a false-positive 500 error with the error-description `(0x0)`.